# VBA - Compare two sheets and highlight changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two sheets. The structure of sheet is absolutely the same -> Cell AD4 in Sheet1 should be same as AD4 in Sheet2, if not, then highlight the AD4 cell. It should be done as far as data exists.

The below code does not work, but it does not show any error message.

```
Sub CompareAndHighlightDifferences()
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, a As Range
Set w1 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail")
Set w2 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail SOURCE")
With w1
  For Each c In .Range("AD4", .Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set a = w2.Columns(30).Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not a Is Nothing Then
      If .Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value <> w2.Cells(a.Row, a.Column) Then
         .Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Font.Color = vbRed
      End If
    End If
  Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Could I ask you for any advices, please?

Many thanks!

---------------------EDIT----------------------

```
Sub CompareAndHighlightDifferences()
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set w1 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail")
Set w2 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail SOURCE")

  For Each c In w1.Range("AD4", w1.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If w1.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value = w2.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value Then
       w1.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
  Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: You might consider using `.CurrentRegion` in order to get the cell, belonging to the same region.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use conditional formatting? (`=A1<>'2019 Project Detail SOURCE'!A1`)

Comment: Your `<>` statement will always be false since you have already determined that the two are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
Sub CompareAndHighlightDifferences()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

Set w1 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail")
Set w2 = Sheets("2019 Project Detail SOURCE")

With w1
    For Each cel In .UsedRange
        If cel.Value <> w2.Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column).Value Then cel.Font.Color = vbRed
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```

*Edit:* If your sheet is protected, you should add `w1.Unprotect` in the beginning and `w1.Protect` at the end.

Comment: Is you sheet protected? If yes, you should unprotect it in the code first. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're searching value in the other sheet, so even if it's not in the same cell address, it will match.

You can remove this and the following if condition:

```
Set a = w2.Columns(30).Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

And use the same address when comparing values:

If .Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value <> w2.Cells(**c**.Row, **c**.Column)**.Value** Then

/e: Also, you might want to use `interior` rather than `font` color because if the cell is blank, there will be a difference that you won't be able to see

Comment: thanks @Daniel, I did that. Unfortunately I received error 1004 on this line:

`.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed`

Comment: Odd, it works for me. this is an object-defined error, are you still using with and en with? If not, just place w1 like so: w1.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed

Comment: I've replaced it, but still the same error. I've edited the code above.

Comment: the sheet has been protected, that's why it did not work. It works like a charm, already. Many thanks!